# Issues with torann/currency composer with requiring illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0

Tags: php, laravel, github, package, composer-php

Everytime I would try to install

`$ composer require torann/currency`
I would get this error

Problem 1

```
    - torann/currency[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.1] require illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires torann/currency ^1.1 -> satisfiable by torann/currency[1.1.0, 1.1.1].
```

I am not sure why and my composer.json looks like this

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "google/recaptcha": "1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.2.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.0",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
    "slim/http": "^1.2",
    "slim/slim": "4.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.75",
    "tcg/voyager": "^1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"repositories": {
    "hooks": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://larapack.io"
    }
}
```

}

I am new to this and hopefully I can get some help. Thank you!

Comment: `torann/currency[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.1] require illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0` but your composer.json uses laravel 5.8 which provides illuminate/support 5.8

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
in this line
change laravel version to `^6.0` or `^7.0` or `^8.0`
then run `composer update` from command